# Locating and opening/ updating the Rprofile.site file in MAC

Tags: r, rstudio

Running RStudio in MAC (not server) and would like to know where to locate the Rprofile.site file in my working directory. Yes I have read `?Startup` and I know exactly what I want to do with it (provided I find the file first) and yes I know where my `getwd()` is.

I have also gone through a bunch of posts in SO already which vaguely touch on/ answer this. Surely this will keep coming up so I will ask the question: Is there a literal file we can open and update with all the great start up code that has been shared and if so, where is it located in a MAC directory OR is there something more to it as I cannot locate this file.

1 answer I found mentions to create a text file then use terminal to copy visible contents of text file to invisible Rprofile? INVISIBLE??

Comment: "MAC" means "media access control."  "Mac" is generic slang for Apple computers.  Capitalization does matter.

Answer (score 1):

`Rprofile.site`  and `.Rprofile` are different files.  Only files with a lead "." are treated as invisible by the Mac Finder.  You didn't specify which OSX version you're using. If it's pre-Mountain Lion, you can IIRC use System Preferences to choose to display invisible files in Finder windows.  Apparently it's more difficult in MountainLion.  There are third-party tools like Onyx which allow you do set invisibility as well.

Given all that,  I recommend you check the FAQ and forums at RStudio for specific info on where RStudio's installation expects to see these files.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Carl. I am running Mountain Lion Version 10.8.4. Also, My question is more about whether we need to create a file or is there a default version that exists (hidden or not) that we need to update with custom settings. Running find in Terminal produces no results.

Comment: Again, check the Rstudio documentation would be the best place to start.